# In F# converting a 2D array of type obj[,] into a sequence of tuples?

Tags: arrays, f#, tuples, sequence

While learning F#, I am given by another library an obj[,] (a 2D array of Objects). The array has two columns and the first column is a long, the second column is a double.

I need to convert this into a sequence of tuples where the first is a System.DateTime which I obtain from converting the long using DateTime.FromOADate and the second column is left unchanged as the second of the tuple.

```
let arrayOfArrays:obj[][] = [| [| 41847; 0.02 |]; [|41877; 0.05 |] |]
let twoDimensionalArray = Array2D.init 2 2 (fun i j -> arrayOfArrays.[i].[j])
```

In this example I need to change twoDimensinalArray to a sequence of tuples with the first element being a tuple with a datetime of 27-Jul-14 and the double 0.02. The second element of the sequence would contain 26-Aug-14 and the double 0.05.

Also I need to perform some checks so I need to be able to insert a function checking each row as a parameter (a validator).

EDIT:
I receive only twoDimensionalArray, I do not have arrayOfArrays (it was in the code sample only to generate twoDimensionalArray).

I tried to amend the code to loop on the rows but the function convertArray does not seem to loop on the `seq`, here is what I tried (in fact the first column is a double as well)

```
let validate (x, y) =
    true
// ... your validation code ...

let convertArray(validate,a:obj[,]) =
    let dateOfInt x = System.DateTime.FromOADate(x)
    // ... convert integer to DateTime
    seq { for rowidx in 0 .. a.GetLength(0) - 1 do
            let row = a.[rowidx, 0 .. (a.GetLength(1)-1)]
            match row with
            // note the use of type test pattern -
            // we need to check the types of row elements
            | [| :? double as x; :? double as y |] ->
                let t = (dateOfInt (float x), y)
                yield
                    if validate t then Some t
                    else None
            | other -> failwithf "Invalid row: %A" other
    }
let arrayOfArrays:obj[][] = [| [| 41847.0; 0.02 |]; [|41877.0; 0.05 |] |]
let twoDimensionalArray = Array2D.init 2 2 (fun i j -> arrayOfArrays.[i].[j]) 
let points = convertArray(validate,twoDimensionalArray)
printfn "%A" (Seq.toList points);;
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to get a sequence of `(DateTime * double) option`, meaning `Some x` for validation pass and `None` for validation fail:

```
let validate (x, y) =
    // ... your validation code ...

let convertArray validate a =
    let dateOfInt x =
        // ... convert integer to DateTime

    seq {
        for row in a do
            match row with
            // note the use of type test pattern -
            // we need to check the types of row elements
            | [| :? int as x; :? double as y |] ->
                let t = (dateOfInt x, y)
                yield
                    if validate t then Some t
                    else None
            | other -> failwithf "Invalid row: %A" other
    }

let twoDimensionalArray = convertArray validate arrayOfArrays
```

You can also rework this to raise an exception when validation fails.

Comment: That is great, I will give it a go when I am back home, I was about to write something that would have been a literal translation of what I would have written in C# but I would like to write some real functional code rather than translating some C# into F#. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my question, I do not have arrayOfArrays, I generated it only to give an example.